# how to fix permission problem in /tmp/.config by deployment Node.js AWS Beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, deployment, permissions, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my React application to Node.js AWS Beanstalk unfortunately getting all the time in /var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log:

```
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.31.28.128/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /var/app/current/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...


┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│             npm update check failed              │
│       Try running with sudo or get access        │
│       to the local update config store via       │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /tmp/.config │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I have tried all possible solutions which I could find including:

- changing permission via config in .ebextensions (many variants checked)
- .npmrc file with unsafe-perm=true in root folder of application(also added to src just to check)
- NPM_CONFIG_UNSAFE_PERM=true in Environment properties
- removing package-lock.json then npm I
- changing instance to more powerful, currently t2.small

Interesting fact is that /tmp/.config has currently enough rights and still it fails

```
drwxrwxrwx  3 ec2-user ec2-user  4096 May  2 12:05 .config
```

Below my files which were deployed via eb deploy(I downloaded from s3)

```
wrmac:app-388c-200502_153210 wojtek$ ls -la
total 1600
drwxr-xr-x@  12 wojtek  staff     384 May  2 20:57 .
drwx------@ 294 wojtek  staff    9408 May  2 20:57 ..
-rw-r--r--@   1 wojtek  staff    6148 May  2 20:57 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x@   4 wojtek  staff     128 May  2 15:22 .ebextensions
-rw-r--r--@   1 wojtek  staff     407 May  1 15:26 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--@   1 wojtek  staff      17 May  2 14:46 .npmrc
-rw-r--r--@   1 wojtek  staff  121322 Sep 29  2018 README.md
-rw-r--r--@   1 wojtek  staff     296 Sep 29  2018 frontend.iml
-rw-r--r--@   1 wojtek  staff  667957 May  2 15:31 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--@   1 wojtek  staff    1035 May  1 22:14 package.json
drwxr-xr-x@  11 wojtek  staff     352 Oct 17  2019 public
drwxr-xr-x@  13 wojtek  staff     416 May  2 14:46 src
wrmac:app-388c-200502_153210 wojtek$ ls -la .ebextensions/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x@  4 wojtek  staff   128 May  2 15:22 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 12 wojtek  staff   384 May  2 20:57 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 wojtek  staff   212 May  2 14:45 00_change_npm_permissions.config
-rw-r--r--@  1 wojtek  staff  3856 Apr 25 15:40 https-redirect-nodejs.config
```

As you can see I do not have node_modules there what was the case for some people.
In .ebignore I excluded also

```
node_modules/
.idea/
.git/
```

(I have tried also excluding .DS_Store, .gitignore and frontend.iml)

I have also two other Environment properties: NODE_ENV and NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION, both true.

To be specific I am using:

```
Platform branch Node.js running on 64bit Amazon Linux Current platform
version 4.14.1 Current Node.js version 12.16.1
```

do you have any ideas what could solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems only solution for this strange AWS specific problem is buying their "Business" support which costs >100$, there is also cheaper option "Developer" support but that might be not enough according to description.

At the end I decided to move to VPS what fully solves my problem(different hosting provider), additionally it is few times cheaper than AWS, I do not have this strange cpu cycles counting, price is easily predictable and probably few other benefits.